# ISupportInitialize in WinForms controls: explicit or implicit implementation?

Tags: winforms, controls, design-time, interface-implementation

I have a custom WinForms control inherited from the WinForms [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control) class. The control also explicitly implements the [System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize) interface used by the WinForms Designer to insert the corresponding `BeginInit`/`EndInit` method calls in the designer's generated code:

```c#
public partial class MyControl : Control, ISupportInitialize
{
    void ISupportInitialize.BeginInit()
    {
        //...
    }

    void ISupportInitialize.EndInit()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is there any difference in the explicit or implicit implementation of `ISupportInitialize` in controls used at design time?

I tried to find an answer in the source code of native .NET components, but found both ways of the interface implementation. For example, [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview) uses the explicit implementation like me, but [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher) does it implicitly. So, is there any difference?

Comment: Do you mean an explicit (private) implementation as `void ISupportInitialize.BeginInit() { /* set some initial state */ }` and the public implementation, as `public void BeginInit() { /* Set states / Set run-time properties / call methods */ }`, which can be called to reset / re-initialize a component at run-time?

Comment: @Jimi, yes. I think that the terms "explicit" and "implicit" are completely definite when we talk about interface implementation.